# Reading in a list of file paths in a Dockerfile and copying each file from one build stage to another

Tags: bash, docker

Overview: 
I am currently trying to dockerize my C++ program in Docker. I am using a multi-stage build structure, where the first stage is responsible for downloading all of the required dependencies and then building/installing them. The second (and final) stage then copies the required executable and shared libraries from the first stage to create the final image. It should also be noted that I need to use this multi-stage structure, as the builder stage uses private ssh keys to clone private git repositories and therefore needs to be purged from the final image.

Problem:
Because the first stage installs packages via apk-add and also clones and installs packages from git, dependencies for my final executable show up in various locations within the filesystem (mainly /usr/lib, /usr/local/lib, /lib). To handle this, in the build stage, I run a 'ldd' command on my main executable with some regex that pipes all of the .so library paths into a text file. I then copy this text file as well as the main executable into the second stage where I would like to read the contents of the text file and copy each line (library path) from the build stage to the second stage. However, given that Dockerfiles do not support looping without a bash script so I don't see a way that I could copy the libraries from the build stage to the final stage. I have attached some code below.  Thank you for the help!

```
#
# ... instructions that install libraries via apk-add and from source
#


# Generate a list of all of the libaries our bin directory depends on and pipe it into a text file
# so our later build stages can copy the absolute minimum neccessary libraries
RUN find /root/$PROJ_NAME/bin -type f -perm /a+x -exec ldd {} \; \
    | grep so \
    | sed -e '/^[^\t]/ d' \
    | sed -e 's/\t//' \
    | sed -e 's/.*=..//' \
    | sed -e 's/ (0.*)//' \
    | sort \
    | uniq  \
    >> /root/$PROJ_NAME/LIBRARY_DEPS.txt


#
# STAGE 2: Build fetched repos and install apk packages
#
FROM alpine:edge




ARG PROJ_NAME
ARG USER_ID
ARG GROUP_ID


# Copy over our main project directory from STAGE 1, which also includes
# the ldd paths of our main executable
COPY --from=builder /root/$PROJ_NAME /root/$PROJ_NAME

# PROBLEM: This is where I am stuck...would like to copy all of the libraries
# whose paths are specified in LIBRARY_DEPS.txt from the builder stage to the current stage
COPY --from=builder (cat /root/$PROJ_NAME/LIBRARY_DEPS.txt) ./

ENTRYPOINT ["./MainExecutable"]
```

Comment: Sorry, but this has nothing to do with git, C++ or Linux-specific APIs, so I removed those tags. Generally, extract and provide a [mcve], which then also helps you focus on the relevant parts. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: In general I’d approach this by installing into some destination tree in the build stage, `COPY` that entire tree into the runtime stage, and separately `apk add` the specific Alpine library packages you need.  I wouldn’t try to copy system libraries from one stage to another.  A slightly more concrete example would help explain further.